# how set a View background color to red and it should be transparent

Tags: react-native

I have a `Imagebackground` for  my `parentconatiner`, I want  to set `backgroundColor` of one of my  `childView` to red and it should be transparent so that the parent container image is visible

it should be like this

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tIwh.jpg)

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import colors from '../styles/colors';
import strings from '../localization/strings';

class Appointments extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.Container}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 0, 0, 0.8)', shadowOpacity: 0.2, padding: 5 }}>

                   <View style={styles.childContainer}>
                            <Image style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start' }} source={require('../assets/calender-Icon.png')}
                            />

                        <View style={styles.dateTextContainer}>
                          <Text style={styles.childText}>Appointment</Text>
                          <Text style={[styles.childText, { fontSize: 26 }]}>Oct24, 2018</Text>   
                          <Text style={[styles.childText, { fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>10:30 am</Text>
                     </View> 
                    </View>


                </View>

                <View style={styles.borderText}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/add-Icon.png')} />
                        <Text style={[styles.itemName, { fontSize: 16 }]}>New</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/seeAll-Icon.png')} />
                    <Text style={[styles.itemName, { fontSize: 16 }]}>See All</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </View>


        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Container: {
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: colors.red
    },
    childContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        margin: 15,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: colors.black,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    childText: {
        color: colors.white,
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    dateTimeContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    dateTextContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    listItem: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: colors.pureBlue,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 5,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        margin: 30
    },
    itemName: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: colors.black,
        margin: 2,
        paddingLeft: 4
    },
    border: {
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: colors.light_gray,
        marginHorizontal: 20
    },
    imageText: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        margin: 10,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 1
    },
    borderText: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        margin: 10
    }

});
export default Appointments;
```

I have tried rgba  and opacity but still not working

please help me how to do this

Comment: did you try opacity https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.6/view-style-props#opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the backgroundColor of the Container to allow for transparency to go all the way through to the parent container, otherwise the transparency will only allow to see the white background behind

```
Container: {
  // backgroundColor: colors.white,
  ...
},
```